# Java application fails with NoClassDefFoundError for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties on Windows

Tags: java, spring, bazel

I have a legacy Java application that I'm trying to run (for the first time) using OpenJDK version "1.8.0_392-392" and Bazel version 6.3.2. The application uses Spring Boot and runs perfectly fine on a friend's Linux system with the same versions of Java and Bazel. I've also tried running it with the newest Bazel version (7.0.0, but switched back to 6.3.2 since that one is running the code fine on Linux) also had different versions of java that didn't work as well (so switched back to 1.8.0_392).

However, when I try to run the same application on Windows, I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

bazel.build file:

```
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary", "java_library", "java_test")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@rules_spring//springboot:springboot.bzl", "springboot")

springboot_deps = [
    "@rules_spring//springboot/import_bundles:springboot_required_deps",
    "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_jetty",
    "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_web",
    "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_loader_tools",
    "@maven//:org_springframework_spring_webmvc",
    "@maven//:javax_annotation_javax_annotation_api",
]

java_library(
    name = "keycloak-service-lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/com/brame/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**/*"]),
    deps = springboot_deps + [
        "@maven//:com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_databind",
        "@maven//:jakarta_servlet_jakarta_servlet_api",
        "@maven//:org_jboss_logging_jboss_logging",
        "@maven//:org_jboss_resteasy_resteasy_jackson2_provider",
        "@maven//:org_jboss_resteasy_resteasy_jaxrs",
        "@maven//:org_keycloak_keycloak_dependencies_server_all",
        "@maven//:org_postgresql_postgresql",
        "@maven//:org_slf4j_slf4j_api",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_configuration_processor",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_actuator",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_data_jdbc",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_starter_data_jpa",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_cloud_spring_cloud_starter_config",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_cloud_spring_cloud_starter_netflix_eureka_client",
        "@maven//:org_springframework_boot_spring_boot_autoconfigure"
    ],
)

springboot(
    name = "keycloak-service-app",
    boot_app_class = "com.brame.AuthorizationServerApp",
    java_library = ":keycloak-service-lib",
)
```

Generated .jar file when bazel build is run does not contain

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties
```

Does anyone have an idea what could I try to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'd probably take the identical version that's working on Linux. Then delete everything under .m2. Rebuild

Comment: Gave it a shot, same error encounters

Comment: Also trying with:
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Did not help

Comment: Is it still working in Linux?

Comment: @g00se Yep, it's working on linux, but on Windows is not working. I've tried also adding spring boot version 3.2.0 in pom.xml, also maven-dependency-plugin and maven-jar-plugin plugins but didn't help.

Comment: Don't vary things in a panic. (Back up first if you like and ) do `rm -rf ~/.m2/*` on Linux. Does it *still* work?

Comment: I do not have a way currently to check it, since friend uses Linux

Comment: I'm wondering if it's working 'accidentally' in Linux

Comment: Not really. A couple of guys from the team are using Linux, no one is using Windows. Everyone on Linux can run it. Maybe to give more context, to run a specific java application, I need to run 2 applications previously, I can run both of them (2.2.6 spring version message shown when it runs successfully). But this third app fails with the errors I provided above. @g00se

Comment: Then you seem to have missed a lot of information from your question and wasted time

Comment: Does this information help with resolving the issue? @g00se

Comment: @g00se adjusted the question with additional information

Comment: I can only offer general troubleshooting advice at this point: check for versioning incompatibilities by looking carefully at the jars used at runtime in working and non-working versions

Comment: In particular, spring-boot-autoconfigure jar